# Wait a dispatch finish to get a state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I open the screen, I want to dispatch an 'edit' action that looks for the item by its id and changes a state property with this information found, then when it get finished, I want to open the screen with this information. I've tried to dispatch on the **Constructor** and set the state from **ComponentDidMount**, but it only appears when I reload component.
Another thing that I noticed is that when I put an alert on the rendering method I could see the array, but when I send it to the '*EditableList*' component it's not shown. Do I need to do an async dispatch?

```
class Observation extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        obs: [],
        get: false
    }
    const { edit, route} = this.props;
    edit(route.params.item.id);
}
onChange(list) {
    this.setState({obs: list})
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({obs: this.props.Obs})
}
render() {
    const {route, add, Obs, loading} = this.props;
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight + 10, backgroundColor: '#FFD618'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 36, padding: 20}}>Observações</Text>
            <EditableList style={{ width: '100%'}} list={this.state.obs} onListChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => add({...route.params.item, obs: this.state.obs})}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Adicionar</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    Obs: state.cart.Obs
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    add: item => dispatch(Add(item)),
    edit: e => dispatch(edit_obs(e))
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Observation);
```

Comment: Why copy redux state to local state instead of using the redux state directly? Your component will re render when redux state changes so if it's not set when the component loads it'll be set after the component dispatched the action on mount.

Comment: It is because the 'EditableList' component will edit this 'obj' state(local) and when the user finishes and adds, it will be saved in another state(redux) that stores the item and its observations. So, when I open this screen again, I wanna preload these stored observations.